# Sticky footer and content scrolling WP

Tags: html, css, overflow, footer, sticky-footer

We have a Wordpress site at http://cmagics.eu/digitalmagazinepublishing which uses the responsive2 theme. We are trying to get a sticky header which seems to work just fine, however we are also trying to get a sticky footer which simply sticks to the bottom of the page and works like the one at http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Because of the slightly cryptic nature of the responsive2 theme how can I;

**1**. keep the footer stuck at the bottom of the page using the correct sticky method not position:fixed

**2**. Stop the main content scrolling unnecessarily when there is plenty of room on the page?

html source:

view-source:http://cmagics.eu/digitalmagazinepublishing/

css

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background: rgb(54, 53, 53);
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #444;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: -324px; **just a hack to make the footer appear at the bottom incorrectly**
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    height: 162px;
    font-family: Roboto Regular;
}

#site-container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 130px auto 0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom:162px;

}

.hfeed {
min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    height: auto;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a solution that I think is very clean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20114486/618649).  Use absolute positioning for all of your main content elements (header, article, footer).  Use @media queries to create breaks at different resolutions if you need to have the header or footer height change for different screen widths (responsive design), and tell your main content area to hide overflow.  You can use floated, relative layouts within the main content areas this way, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is footer css :-

```
#footer {
         position: fixed;
         font-size: 11px;
         line-height: 1.5em;
         background: rgb(54, 53, 53);
         color: #fff;
         border-top: 2px solid #444;
         text-align: center;
         margin-top: -324px;
         margin-bottom: -25px;
         height: 162px;
         font-family: Roboto Regular;
         bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

Comment: Hi pramod, I wanted to use the sticky footer example shown in the link, where you dont have to use position fixed.